# Vue 3, Quasar Framework, open page in modal

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, quasar-framework

On click on link, I'm need to change route and open page in modal, but if page reloaded or visited via link, page must load as page (not in modal). Is it possible?

As example a Bitrix24 profile page:
[image]

Comment: I`m need to save state of opened  page before changing of route. If user close modal, route must change back...

Comment: As example in list of orders, user click on customer and I`m need to open customer profile page in modal (with change url in browser). And this customer page must open as standalone page if user refresh page or visit via direct link on customer profile